# How to marshal a list in C#

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I have to send a list from C# to C++.The C# list is `List<string>MyList` and the C++ code accepts it as `list<wstring>cppList`.How to use marshalas for this.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt you can use MarshalAs for this. A C# `List` is contiguous, while a C++ `list` is a linked list. C#'s `List<T>` is more like `vector<T>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always wiser not to use complex type marshaling between native code and managed code.
In case of `List`, these type totally differ from each other as they have different memory layout for each item.

So the best way is to write a utility function in a native dll that accepts array of string(char*) and manually build your native `List` and ultimately call the desired method. It is easy for your to create wrapper of that utility function.

Answer (score 3):

C# cannot P/Invoke complex C++ types. You will have to use C++/CLI, they might have a method for marshalling it across. Else, you will have to marshal each string across individually.

Answer (score 0):

`strings` in C# are `wstrings` (2 byte unicode strings), so if what you say is true, then no special conversions are necessary.

Comment: It's a list of strings rather than an individual string.

Comment: A C# `string` is indeed a UTF-16 Unicode string. C++'s `wstring` isn't, though. Neither Unicode, nor 2-byte characters.

Comment: @Martinho On Windows `wstring` is the natural way to hold a UTF-16 string.