# How do i marshal list<int>?

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I have a dll in c++, it returns list, I want to use it in my c# app as List

```
[DllImport("TaskLib.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern List<int> GetProcessesID();

public static List<int> GetID()
{
    List<int> processes = GetProcessesID();//It is impossible to pack a "return value": The basic types can not be packed
    //...
}
```

Comment: `std::list<>` and `System.Collections.Generic.List<>` are unalike in every possible way. Unless you write a C++/CLI shim, your C++ code will need to work in terms of POD types only -- returning standard library objects is never going to work.

Comment: The opposite question (marshalling and passing a list from C# to C++) has been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6532923/960195) and might prove helpful.

Comment: The only way I think you can do this kind of marshaling is by writing a C++/CLI intermediate function to perform "manually" the conversion.

Comment: @MatteoItalia should this c++ function return int* or anything else?

Comment: @loshurik: the C++/CLI bridge function, being able to work with both `std::list<>` and .NET's `List<>` should return `List<>`, after filling it with the data got from the `std::list<>`.

Comment: @loshurik : No, because then you will neither know the length of the list, nor how to deallocate the memory. Your best bets are either a C++/CLI shim, or to have the function take a pre-allocated buffer and populate it (as opposed to returning a newly-allocated one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per Jared Par:

> Generics as a rule are not supported in any interop scenario. Both PInvoke and COM Interop will fail if you attempt to Marshal a generic type or value. Hence I would expect Marshal.SizeOf to be untested or unsupported for this scenario as it is a Marshal specific function.

See:
[Marshalling .NET generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579559/marshalling-net-generic-types)

Answer (score 3):

one of possible scenarios

c++ side

```
    struct ArrayStruct
    {
        int myarray[2048];
        int length;
    };

    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void GetArray(ArrayStruct* a)
    {
        a->length = 10;
        for(int i=0; i<a->length; i++)
            a->myarray[i] = i;
    }
```

c# side

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct ArrayStruct
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2048)]
        public int[] myarray;
        public int length;
    }

    [DllImport("TaskLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void GetArray(ref ArrayStruct a);

    public void foo()
    {
        ArrayStruct a = new ArrayStruct();
        GetArray(ref a);
    }
```